# Android Lint Tool

Tags: android, android-lint

I have updated my Android SDK to Revision 16 but I can't seem to find 
[Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/recent/lint)

anywhere in my Eclipse IDE (Preferences -> Android). Are there any additional things to be done? I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Also lint command not working in /sdk/tools/ directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you installed it firstly, by checking pulgins installed.

Then right click the project, go android tools, there is a "Run Lint"

Comment: Yup, looked into the Plugins installed, what is the provider name? Android Lint Project?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It is part of adt, you can only see it when installing. Just see if you have the Run Lint item in android tool popup menu. If none, try to uninstall adt and re-install it with "android lint" checked.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no menu point in eclipse (`Window -> Run Android Lint`), chances are that you only upgraded your Android SDK and not the eclipse plugin. In this case go to `Help -> Check for updates`. Eclipse should tell you that there are new updates available. Just click next to install them. Then restart eclipse when prompted.

Comment: I'm running Version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604. Is this the latest version? My company blocks sites from Eclipse, I can't confirm and update. I'll try this one if they don't block sites anymore. Thanks.

Comment: This is the eclipse version, which is not too relevant here. Relevant is the version of the android tools. Go to `Help -> Install new Software` and click on the small link `Whats already installed?`. You should find *Android Development tools* under the `Installed Software` tab. The most recent version is `16.0.1.v201112150204-238534`. If you version starts with 15, the plugin is out of date.