# Lint not detecting project errors, although they are marked. 

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-lint

I was recently going over the CustomView tutorial on developers.android.com, and while I was adapting the code to my own project, I noticed that although the errors were marked, line-by-line in the class editor, they were going entirely undetected by lint.

So far, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569704/android-lint-tool?rq=1) & an article that suggested I simply "Save Perspective As..." and restart Eclipse.

[image]

I imagine this is an easy-to-fix problem, that I may have unknowingly caused, myself... 
Because errors in other projects show up in Lint just fine.

Perhaps I need to find the lint.xml as described in [this](http://bit.ly/Mzd2QD) question-?-
Any idea where that may be?

Comment: Lint is not a Java compiler and does not check Java compile error like "ValueAnimator cannot be resloved to a type".

Comment: Well, it has always detected every error... and marked it on the file-icon to the left. 
Plus, as I highlighted on the right, I have dozens of other errors that are not showing up in lint... 
Furthermore, when I create new ones (since I thought "Clear Lint Warnings" might be responsible for this), such as erasing the constructor method- it will not detect those, either, although it does get highlighted in the editor.

Comment: check out [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/) to see what kind of errors Lint check.

Comment: Ok, we're getting warmer. I apologize for not making my issue clear, but thank you for your feedback-- but check it out: 
 I went to a class in the same project, screwed up the package name, and although the editor marks the line and the error shows up in the editor-- it does *not* show up in lint, even after cleaning the project and manually running lint. Additionally, the error icon does not show up on the file icon in the Package Explorer pane. 

This is likely something stupid that i unknowingly did- and probably has a simple fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with this for quite some time, it would appear that the solution came from one of the following two things, if not both.

`$ sudo chown me /myproject/`

How I lost the ownership in the first place, I may never know.

And I also re-enabled "Java Builders" under the Builder property for the project. 
This is a solution for some problems, but not in this case. 
Now everything is back to normal.